Species of permutations with only even cycle lengths
Let $e(2n)$ be the number of permutations $\sigma $ of a set of $2n$ elements with the property that every cycle of $\sigma $ has even length. Find the exponential generating function $\sum_{n} e(2n) x^{2n} / (2n)!$.
I saw an older post Number of permutations with all cycles of even length, but I want to use the theory of combinatorial species to solve this question. I have tried breaking the permutation species into parts, i.e. letting $P$ and $P_n$ denote the species of all permutations and the species of permutations with only cycle of lengths $n$, respectively. Then $P(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x},$ and $P = (1 + P_1)(1 + P_2)(1 + P_3)\dots$, and the species for all even length cycles would be given by $(1 + P_2)(1+P_4)\dots$.
However, I am not too sure where to go from here. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated!

Please note that given species $F_1, \ldots, F_k$, structures of species of type $F_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes F_k$ on a finite set $S$ are elements of $$\sum_{S = S_1 + \ldots + S_n} F_1[S_1] \times \ldots \times F_k[S_k]$$ where the indexing is over an ordered partitions $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ of $S$. It's that ordering that can throw some things off.

Perhaps relevant, though not using species: Counting permutations (Ethan D. Bolker and Andrew M. Gleason)
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316580900126

The species itself is of the form $\exp \circ A$ where $A$ is the species of cyclic permutations of positive even length. (More generally, for a species $F$ such that $F[0]$ is the empty set, structures of species $(\exp \circ F)[S]$ are ways of partitioning a finite set $S$ and putting an $F$-structure on each class of the partition.)
The egf of $A$ is
$$|A|(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{x^{2n}}{2n}$$
for the same reason that the egf of the species $C$ of cyclic permutations (on nonempty finite sets) generally is
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n} = \log \frac1{1-x}.$$
(The principle is the same as before: the species $P$ of permutations generally is $\exp \circ C$. Since permutations are equinumerous with linear orderings, and the species for those has egf $\sum_{n \geq 0} n! \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac1{1-x}$, we get the result.)
The derivative of $|A|(x)$ is $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$, which together with $|A|(0) = 0$ yields
$$|A|(x) = -\frac1{2}\log(1 - x^2)$$
and so
$$|\exp \circ A|(x) = (1 - x^2)^{-1/2}$$
where the coefficient $e(2n)$ is easily read off from the binomial theorem as
$$(2n)! (-1)^n \left(-\frac1{2}\right)^{\underline{n}}\frac1{n!}$$
which involves a falling power
$$\left(-\frac1{2}\right)^{\underline{n}} = (-1)^n \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{2^n}.$$
The signs cancel, so if I haven't made a mistake,
$$e(2n) = [(2n-1)!!]^2.$$
It would be interesting to lift this to a structural isomorphism. Please let me know if this is what you really were asking for.
